# How to force gmap inside center layout of primefaces redraw after window size has been changed?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, primefaces

I am using primefaces layouts for displaying web page. Map is Located in the center Layout

```
 here<p:layoutUnit position="center" resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false" collapsed="false" styleClass="ui-layout-center" >

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true|false"
    type="text/javascript"/>


<h:form>
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" life="4000" />
    <p:gmap id ="map" center="#{mapBean.latCenter}, #{mapBean.lonCenter}" zoom="#{mapBean.zoomLevel}" type="ROADMAP"
        style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%" model="#{mapBean.model}"  widgetVar="gmap">
        <p:ajax event="stateChange" listener="#{mapBean.onStateChange}"
            update="messages, map" fixBounds="false"/>
    </p:gmap>
```

Also to find that window size has been changed I use java script

```
        function initialize() {

        var gmap = PF('gmap').getMap();
        var currentCenter = gmap.getCenter();
        gmap.setCenter(currentCenter);

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', initialize);
```

But when I change the size of the window - map is shown partially. If I make browser's window bigger the map is displayed with the size from previous small window. Helps only when I move map. After moving map, map is redrawed correctly. I tried to use

```
google.maps.event.trigger(gmap, "resize");
```

but it hasn't helped. Result is below

[Result of changing size of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWPIf.jpg)

How can be solved this problem using javaScript and Primefaces?

Comment: Use a searchengine: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17033

Comment: This solution has not worked for me. I copied code  function callMap() {
            var gmap = PF('gmap').getMap();
            resize_map();
            
            google.maps.event.trigger(gmap, "resize");
        }
  
  function resize_map() {
         var iWidth = $(window).width();
         var iHeight = $(window).height();
         $("#map").height(iHeight  - 50 - 100);
         $("#map").width(iWidth - 300 - 200);
      }
      $(window).ready(function () {
          resize_map();
      });
      $(window).resize(function () {
          resize_map();
 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem.

1) I have inspected page with Inspect Element option
2) Fount that form is transformed in div
3) On the google API I have found getDiv()
4) Update style of div
5) Next code is working

```
window.onresize = function(event) {

        var map = PF('gmapV').getMap();
        var MyDiv = map.getDiv();
        var height = $(window).height() - 50 - 100;
        var width = $(window).width() - 300 - 200;
        MyDiv.style.width = width.toString().concat("px");
        MyDiv.style.height = height.toString().concat("px");
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

    }
```